# Pyspark BinaryClassficationMetrics areaUnderROC

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

--Edit on 29Jun 2016
Hi,
Following is the error log for the command:

```
metrics = BinaryClassificationMetrics(labelsAndPreds)

# Area under ROC curve
#print("Area under ROC = %s" % metrics.areaUnderROC)
metrics.areaUnderROC
```

### Error Log:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-36c9c8730e9d> in <module>()
      4 # Area under ROC curve
      5 #print("Area under ROC = %s" % metrics.areaUnderROC)
----> 6 metrics.areaUnderROC

/home/shenbaga/spark-1.6.1/python/pyspark/mllib/evaluation.pyc in areaUnderROC(self)
     60         (ROC) curve.
     61         """
---> 62         return self.call("areaUnderROC")
     63 
     64     @property

/home/shenbaga/spark-1.6.1/python/pyspark/mllib/common.pyc in call(self, name, *a)
    144     def call(self, name, *a):
    145         """Call method of java_model"""
--> 146         return callJavaFunc(self._sc, getattr(self._java_model, name), *a)
    147 
    148 

/home/shenbaga/spark-1.6.1/python/pyspark/mllib/common.pyc in callJavaFunc(sc, func, *args)
    121     """ Call Java Function """
    122     args = [_py2java(sc, a) for a in args]
--> 123     return _java2py(sc, func(*args))
    124 
    125 

/home/shenbaga/spark-1.6.1/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
    811         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    812         return_value = get_return_value(
--> 813             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
    814 
    815         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/home/shenbaga/spark-1.6.1/python/pyspark/sql/utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
     43     def deco(*a, **kw):
     44         try:
---> 45             return f(*a, **kw)
     46         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     47             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/home/shenbaga/spark-1.6.1/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    306                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    307                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 308                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    309             else:
    310                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o254.areaUnderROC.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 13.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 16, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException: Value at index 1 in null
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getAnyValAs(Row.scala:475)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getDouble(Row.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getDouble(rows.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:61)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.RangePartitioner$.sketch(Partitioner.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.RangePartitioner.<init>(Partitioner.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.OrderedRDDFunctions$$anonfun$sortByKey$1.apply(OrderedRDDFunctions.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.OrderedRDDFunctions$$anonfun$sortByKey$1.apply(OrderedRDDFunctions.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.OrderedRDDFunctions.sortByKey(OrderedRDDFunctions.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.x$4$lzycompute(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.x$4(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.confusions$lzycompute(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.confusions(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.createCurve(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.roc(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics.areaUnderROC(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Value at index 1 in null
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getAnyValAs(Row.scala:475)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getDouble(Row.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getDouble(rows.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(BinaryClassificationMetrics.scala:61)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more


**strong text**
```

--Original Question
I am trying to create a Confusion Matrix for a Logistic Regression model created in pyspark. I see from documentation examples that we can use BinaryClassificationMetrics to get the confusion matrix. But I get errors even if I run the example given in the documentation!

```
scoreAndLabels = sc.parallelize([
   (0.1, 0.0), (0.1, 1.0), (0.4, 0.0), (0.6, 0.0),
   (0.6, 1.0), (0.6, 1.0), (0.8, 1.0)], 2)

metrics = BinaryClassificationMetrics(scoreAndLabels)

metrics.areaUnderROC
```

This gives an error:

> An error occurred while calling o232.areaUnderROC.
>   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 74.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 74.0 (TID 793, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException: Value at index 1 in null

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It works when I tried. Maybe you could paste the complete code and error logs?

Comment: Hi Shuaiyuancn - Thanks for the note. I tried the same code and I did not get any errors as you had mentioned. However, when I tried the same function in my larger program, I still get errors. I have edited the original question with the error log. Appreciate your help in advance :)

Answer (score 5):

I have found the error in my code. Both label and prediction in labelsAndPreds should be *float* for the code to work. In my earlier code, the predictions were not float and that was the reason for the error.

Thanks

Comment: how did you find that was the problem even I had same issue and I converted it solve the problem, I didn't make out anything from error message